# Как сделать ввод и вывод по char если они есть по int?

Tags: c++, вывод, ввод

Как мне сделать ввод и вывод по char если у меня есть они по int.

Условие задачи: даны координаты коня на шахматной доске. Необходимо вывести все координаты клеток на которые он может попасть за один ход.
Пример: Ввод: b7 Вывод: d6 c5 d8 a5. Моя программа:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   int x, y;
cin >> x >> y;
    for (int i=0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<8; j++) {
            int dx=abs(x - i);
            int dy=abs(y - j);
            if (((dx == 1) && (dy == 2)) || ((dx == 2) && (dy == 1))) cout << i+1 << ' ' << j+1 << endl;}}
}
```

Я вместо b7 ввожу 2 7, а вывожу 4 6, 3 5, 4 8, 1 5. То есть соответствующие буквам цифры. Как мне сделать ввод и вывод как в условии посредством char?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, например, так:

```
char c; int x, y;
cin >> c >> y;  x = с - 'a';  // Для 'a' - 0. Если надо 1 - x = с - 'a' + 1;

.....

cout << char('a'+i)
```